# Rails API Session Security and CSRF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, session

I am doing an api with Rails(api-only). Security is so importand for me. I got 2 question. 1-) I am keeping user's id in session[:authID], is it safe to use like this? 2-) Do i need CSRF protection for api-only? I'm using Next.js for client. If it is needed, how can i?

Comment: 1. Security is not a boolean proposition and thinking of it as such often leads to insecure code. All code is potentially insecure - the question really just how much. The session is generally as secure against reading/tampering as the secret you're using to encrypt it with and the encryption algorith. This is also extremely dependent on other facctors like if your app is volunerable to session fixation attacks or enumeration attacks so it really depends entirely on how well your authentication system is implemented.

Comment: 2. It depends. The Rails CRSF mechanism is based on storing a secret in the session so it relies on the use of cookies. That is a problem if you want to create an API that is also usable by non-browser clients like for example server to server or native apps. If your API is just serving your own single page application and that application lives on the same domain it is still usable though.

Answer (score -1):

Q1. I am keeping user's id in session[:authID], is it safe to use like this?

*ANS* - It's **not good** practice to keep user ids in session as it reveals your table structure (not fully but still) like where your **user table's primary key starts from**. Rather than that you can use **device-token-auth** gem (details can be found [here](https://medium.com/@tunbosunogunlana1/authentication-api-with-rails-6-0-and-device-token-auth-gem-39ca1ad0520e) and [here](https://dev.to/risafj/guide-to-devisetokenauth-simple-authentication-in-rails-api-pfj))

Q2. Do i need CSRF protection for api-only?

*ANS* - Cross-Site or Cross-Session Request Forgery requires a user to have a browser and another trusted website. This is **not relevant for APIs**, since they ***don't*** run in the browser and ***don't maintain any*** session. Therefore, you should **disable** CSRF for APIs. You can check [here](https://medium.com/codex/deploying-a-rails-api-react-app-with-sessions-and-csrf-tokens-d33d2924639) for details.

Hope the brief helps you.

Thank you

Comment: Q1. According to whom? Almost all applications using session based authentication store a user id in the session and a primary key that starts at 1. Using token based auth to simply hide that is nothing but security by obscurity and has no real security benefit. Stateless authentication does have other benefits though.

Comment: Q2. This question is more complex then you're letting on. Not all APIs are intended to be used for cross domain applications or anything else then a feeding JSON to a  SPA framework. While there are alternatives like stateless CSRF protection using HMAC Tokens that work cross domain the Rails anti-CSRF system isn't completely irrevant for APIs if you accept its limitations.

Comment: Q2. I think your answer is much more complicating than the question itself. I haven't experienced  using CSRF for API apps.